400 Bad request in jQuery AJAX
I am sending form data from jQuery AJAX to ColdFusion CFC. It is working fine with 100 form parameters. If I send more (more inputs from form), it is throwing 400 bad request in the response. I am pulling my hair out for last 2 hours. Couldnt find the reason.
Here is the ajax call that I am using.
$.ajax({
    url: 'cfc/main.cfc?method=submitData',
    async : false,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#workStationForm').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}); 

Here is my cfc function (currently just dumping the arguments to find out the reason, but no hint for anything except bad request). Request payload seems to be correct. If I add more than 100 form params, I am facing this issue.
<cffunction name="submitData" returntype="any" access="remote" returnformat="json"> 
    <cfdump var="#arguments#" abort>
</cffunction>



